# video and audio in (ie) browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Dears,

I have made HTML helper that play video and audio

and when I do change from (7 default) to (9, 10 or edge) it does work correctly
how I can fix it to be to latest.
what do i need to do?

this is my code for the helper

```
public static IHtmlString Media(this HtmlHelper helper, string width, string height, string src, bool isYoutubeOrVimeo = false, string type = "video")
        {
            if (type == "audio")
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(@"<audio controls>
  <source src='{0}' type='audio/ogg'>
  <source src='{0}' type='audio/mpeg'>
<source src='{0}' type='audio/wav'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>", src));

            }
            else
            {
                if (isYoutubeOrVimeo == false)
                {
                    return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(@"<video width='{0}' height='{1}' controls>
  <source src='{2}' type='video/mp4'>
  <source src='{2}' type='video/ogg'>
  <source src='{2}' type='video/webm'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>", width, height, src));
                }
                else
                {
                    Regex VimeoVideoRegex = new Regex(@"vimeo\.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    Regex YoutubeVideoRegex = new Regex(@"^(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v\=))([\w-]{10,12})(?:$|\&|\?\#).*");
                    Match youtubeMatch = YoutubeVideoRegex.Match(src);
                    Match vimeoMatch = VimeoVideoRegex.Match(src);
                    string id = string.Empty;
                    if (youtubeMatch.Success)
                    {
                        id = youtubeMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(@"<iframe width='{0}' height='{1}' src='{2}' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>", width, height, "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id));
                    }
                    if (vimeoMatch.Success)
                        id = vimeoMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                    return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format(@"<iframe width='{0}' height='{1}' src='{2}' frameborder='0'></iframe>", width, height, "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + id));
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, use the **File>Properties menu** to determine **which IE Security zone** your test site is mapped to. By default localhost subdomains map to the Internet Zone. If your localhost instead, maps to the INTRANET zone, then it will assume a default Emulation Mode of IE7 (see **tools>Compatibility View Settings>"Display intranet sites in compatibility view"**) and will not support/render html5 media elements and also will only run 32bit BHO's, toolbars, or ActiveX controls (32bit cpu's of coarse cant run 64 bit code).

from IE go Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, Fist click the "Reset all zones to default" button, to reset your dev machine's browser security settings back to their factory or company GPO defaults.

Then select...

Intranet Zone>Advanced button, remove localhost or 127.0.0.1 from your list. Save your changes.

Return to IE and refresh your test website page. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to again confirm that it is now mapping to the INTERNET security zone. Use the Emulation tab of the IE dev tool to confirm that it is now assuming Edge emulation mode (IE11) and so is capable of supporting HTML5 media elements.

However, your screenshot indicates that your BHO is not even loaded in an IE 32bit tab process... You need to deploy both a 32bit and 64bit version of your BHO that will work on both 32bit processors and 64bit processes/tabs.... by default IE on 64bit processors will only load 64bit BHO's on tabs that load a website that maps to the Internet (or Restricted) zone(s).

Your BHO (which automatically injects content in a web page without a user action) is likely to be flagged as malware when deployed in the wild... please see the following links for 'Best Practices' for IE Addon development.

http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130949(v=vs.85).aspx